# How to delete a word after a particular charcater in a string android

Tags: java, android

"repname":"","state":"","website":""}]","buildingdetails"

I want to delete a " after a ]only at one place 
can u give a suggestions how to delete it

thanx in advance

Comment: try something like.. `String s = s.replace(s.charAt(s.IndexOf(])+1),"you desired char");`.

Comment: @sourabhbans You mean `... IndexOf("[")...`

Comment: @BobMalooga  i mean `]` ... he want to delete a `"` after a `]` ...n ofcourse  there should be quotes (" ").. forgot to write...

Comment: @sourabhbans Yes, of course. I meant the missing `"`s.

Comment: @BobMalooga thats why i wrote... `something like`...on the startup of the comment.. ;)

Comment: @sourabhbans have a nice day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
int index = input.indexOf("]");

String result = input.substring(0, index+1) + input.substring(index + 2);
```